# Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: visualforce.el.VisualforceArrayList

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following code which gives me below error.

> Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: visualforce.el.VisualforceArrayList

The VF Page I developed.

```
<apex:page controller="ApexRestController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:commandButton reRender="table1" value="Get Case Details" action="{!getCaseDetailsById}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="table1">
            <b>Output Contact Details </b>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caList}" var="ca">
                <apex:column headerValue="CaseNumber" value="{!ca.CaseNumber}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!ca.Subject}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!ca.Status}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**And Controller class**

```
public class ApexRestController {
    public List<Case> caList {get; set;}

    public static String getAccessToken(){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');

        String CLIENT_ID = 'XX';
        String CLIENT_SECRET = 'XX';
        String USERNAME = 'XX';
        String PASSWORD = 'XX';

        req.setBody('grant_type=password' + '&client_id='+CLIENT_ID + 
            '&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET + '&username='+USERNAME + '&password='+PASSWORD);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        String access_token = res.getBody();
        return access_token;
    } 

    public List<Case> getCaseDetailsById(){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/XX');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+getAccessToken());

        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        String json = res.getBody();

        Case ca = (Case) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Case.class);
        caList = new List<Case>();
        caList.add(ca);
        return caList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getCaseDetailsById() should not be returning List instead it should be returning PageReference (or) Void

Comment: Hey Thnx working, what PageReference is only working ?

Comment: Sorry , can you  please explain , i am not able to get it .

Comment: Why PageReference method es expected to the salesforce? Why List<> does not get worked ?

Comment: When action method is invoked the system invokes a GET / POST method . When you do a GET/POST method it implicitly means that the system will do a request -response . When the response comes back it may in various format xml,html,xhtml ,xhr anything which the browser has to render visually. This is one part to it . But on the other hand salesforce as a system will try to redirect you to some page after action has been performed and the data type it looks is only PageReference / void - If it solves your query mark it so that people will know that this solution may work for them - THanks

Answer (score 0):

If you change the return type of your `getCaseDetailsById` method to `PageReference`, update `caList` and return `null` from the method, the page will post back with the updates to `caList`.